# Nlog to Send Email Alerts during certain times during the day

Tags: c#, nlog

Is there a way I can filter Nlog to send email alerts only during certain times during the day (For example, Monday - Friday from 8am - 7pm)?

It's a console application configured to be used as Windows Service using TopShelf.

Answer (score 2):

You could use filters for that. Something like this:

```xml
<logger name="*" writeTo="myMailTarget">
  <filters defaultAction='Log'>
    <when condition="${date:format=H} >= 20" action="Ignore" />
    <when condition="${date:format=H} <= 6" action="Ignore" />
  </filters>
</logger>
```

See

https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages and https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Date-Layout-Renderer